Is the first I/O apic in the MADT table special?
Is the first I/O APIC in the madt table special? Is it always supposed to contain all the ISA IRQs if there is no legacy PIC? I heard this is called the boot-APIC, do you have a reference?

Looks like the question ended up being posted twice. Please delete the other one
